# How do I display text next to a drop down menu?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to put this drop down menu next to this text 'Vlerat mesatare dhe ekstremet prej vitit 1940 sipas muajit:' but what I get is a drop down menu below the text. Could someone help me please?

```
<form name="Zgjidhni muajin">
        <select name="Zgjidhni muajin" onChange="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
            <option selected="selected">Zgjidhni muajin...</option>
            <option value="http://meteotirana.altervista.org/joomla/images/Klima/Slide2.PNG">Janar</option>
            <option value="http://meteotirana.altervista.org/joomla/images/Klima/Slide3.PNG">Shkurt</option>
            <option value="http://meteotirana.altervista.org/joomla/images/Klima/Slide4.PNG">Mars</option>
            <option value="http://meteotirana.altervista.org/joomla/images/Klima/Slide5.PNG">Prill</option>

        </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show the html related to the text. It sounds like it is in a block element. See [mcve]

Comment: I'm working on WYSIWYG editor and the code is added with a plugin to the editor, therefore what I see around the code is just text that I'm writing on that page.